# Line-height on nav in safari is different than every other browser

Tags: safari, css

I have looked all over for a solution to this problem and nothing seems to work and I really don't want to use a hack if I can avoid it.

When I set the line-height to vertically center my nav it's centered everywhere but safari, it's sitting about 2px high. Here is the css for the nav bar:

```
nav {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0;
font-size: 16px;
height: 25px;
```

}

```
nav ul {
padding-left: 0px;
margin: 0;
line-height: 1.5em;
```

}

```
nav li{
display: inline;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding-right: 12px;
padding-left: 12px;
```

}

I've tried line-height in px, em, and % and it's still wrong in safari. Here is a screenshot of the correct nav position in firefox and the wrong position in safari.

[image: nav issue]

Any help on this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: try setting the ratio instead of ems, eg line-height: 1.5625;  instead of 1.5em. (25/16) this solved my line-height issues on iOS safari...

Answer (score 2):

Some browser specific default styles could be interfering your defined styles. (Inherited styles, default more specifically defined styles for certain elements...)

For homogenous behavior in all browsers, use a CSS reset and define all the needed styles properly, not depending on browsers' defaults.

Here is a good source: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: I have the same problem & tried setting "line-height:1" as a reset, the line height behavior still seems buggy.

Comment: Css reset worked for me. In my case "button" tag was not vertical aligned with "li" tag, inside Nav for safari. I fixed it with help of following link.
https://css-tricks.com/overriding-default-button-styles/